# Why are the values of my object changing?

Tags: angular

In the following function, the variable credentials is passed in as a parameter. I log the values of the credentials object to the console and they are as expected. Then I convert credentials to a string using JSON.stringify() and the values are changed.

This is the function.

```
public signIn(credentials) {
    console.log('credentials', credentials) 

    let body = JSON.stringify(credentials);
    console.log('body', body)

    return this.httpClient.post(this.userUrl, body, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      tap(token => console.log('token', token)),
      catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))
    )    
  }
```

console.log('credentials', credentials) produces the following values with every value having an X as the first letter:

```
credentials 
Object
email: "Xadmin@admin.com"
name: "XJohn Admin"
password: "Xadmin"
__proto__: Object
```

console.log('body', body) produces the following values with the initial X missing:

```
body {"name":"John Admin","email":"admin@admin.com","password":"admin"}
```

Comment: Is `credentials` modified later? When you output an object to the console, you see the updated properties when clicking on the arrow, not the values they had when `console.log` was called.

Comment: We need to see more of the code....

Comment: @ConnorsFan That is the entire function shown. There is no further modification of credentials.

Comment: But `credentials` is passed as a parameter, so it is coming from somewhere else. What happens to the original variable afterwards?

Comment: @ConnorsFan You pointed me in the right direction. In the calling component, I mistakenly called UserService.signin() from the ngInit() function instead of the signIn() function as I intended. Thanks and I hope Connor wins tomorrow..